# Double click event not working in Internet Explorer for option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML CODE :

```
<select name="options" id="options" style="width: 100%;" size="12">
        <option id="optList1" value="1">
            1. ABC
        </option>
</select>
```

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('optList1').ondblclick = function () {
            alert("asf");
        };
```

I am having list in of options in select , in sample there is only one item . Issue is I need to open dialog box on double click of this option... Its working fine in Chrome and Firefox , issue is common , not working in IE....

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yw6kv/5/)**

Any help super appreciated... Thanks in advance....!!

Comment: Where are you using jquery ? Or did you mean to say you wanted a jquery answer?

Comment: I also tried with jQuery bt result was same it was not working... if you know that jQuery can solve this...  we can use... not issue....!!

Comment: You can't do this in IE. `select` element is created by OS, not by browser.

Comment: @Teemu any link..... to support this....!!

Comment: @PratikBhatt I'm sorry, I can't recall the page at MSDN, and having not time to search just now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('options').ondblclick = function () {
       var optio = options.options;
var id      = options[options.selectedIndex].id;
   if(id == "optList1")
   {
      alert("abc");
   }
   else 
   {
      alert("xyz")
   }
};


<select name="options" id="options" style="width: 100%;" size="12">
    <option id="optList1" value="1.1">
        2. Enter/Update W/H Data Manually
    </option>
    <option id="optList2" value="1.1">
        1. Enter/Update W/H Data Manually
    </option>
```

Try this code its working fine on IE

Answer (score 2):

IE does not support events on `<option>` tag.

Also seems strange to consider a doubleclick event on `<option>` as this is not anything most users would be used to doing

Comment: yes.... I know.. its freaking to use double click on option... bt nothing can be done,... we need to use this

Comment: could try dblick on select but still not user friendly `have to use it` is bad excuse for design problem